# Prettier setting to preserve space directly below function declaration

Tags: javascript, typescript, whitespace, code-formatting, prettier

For example if we have this in a .ts file:

```
export const handleHMRMessages = (cache: any, store: CPReduxStore, conn: WebSocket) => {

  conn.onclose = () => {
    store.dispatch(actions.dev.hmrDisconnected());
  };
}
```

prettier will remove all carriage returns above the first line of code in the func body:

```
export const handleHMRMessages = (cache: any, store: CPReduxStore, conn: WebSocket) => {
  conn.onclose = () => {
    store.dispatch(actions.dev.hmrDisconnected());
  };
}
```

so I have been resorting to adding a comment above the declaration to preserve the space:

```
export const handleHMRMessages = (cache: any, store: CPReduxStore, conn: WebSocket) => {
  // add comment here as needed
  conn.onclose = () => {
    store.dispatch(actions.dev.hmrDisconnected());
  };
}
```

is there a prettier setting that can always have no more and no less space below a function declaration?

Answer (score 2):

No. Prettier is an [opinionated formatter](https://prettier.io/docs/en/option-philosophy.html) with limited configurability and is designed this way on purpose. The available options are listed [here](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html).